# How can I join Multiple android system_.img files to create one single system.img file

Tags: android, system, android-source, cyanogenmod, rom

I have Stock rom for Lenovo Vibe K5 Plus and Lenovo Zuk Z1. But the system.img file is partitioned in multiple system_1.img system_2.img etc images. I want to get a single system.img image , so that it can be flashed through fastboot. Can someone help here ?

Answer (score 0):

use any file joiner softer to join those files 
Such as : http://www.igorware.com/file-joiner

Comment: I tried .but the final .img file becomes corrupt and can't be flashed to android device.